# How to stop & restart routing in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

It is necessary to check the status of the application before you start routing. Stop if a condition is met, and continue again at will.

How can this be done with Aurelia?

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what you are asking but if you are setting up routing and want your application to wait until it is finished you can return a promise from the `configureRouter` method -

```
export class App {
  configureRouter(router) {
    //...
    return new Promise((res, rej) => { res(true); });
  }
}
```

for instance